# how to scan another library with structure map

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, structuremap

I have a class library that called ServiceLayer which contains the below code:

IProductService.cs

```
public interface IProductService
{
    void AddNewProduct(Product product);
    IList<Product> GetAllProducts();
}
```

ProductService.cs

```
public class ProductService : IProductService
{
    readonly IDbSet<Product> _products;

    public ProductService(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _products = uow.Set<Product>();
    }

    public void AddNewProduct(Product product)
    {
        _products.Add(product);
    }

    public IList<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return _products.Include(x => x.Category).ToList();
    }
}
```

I installed Structuremap.MVC5, so in `DefaultRegistry` file i have the below code:

DefaultRegistry.cs

```
 public DefaultRegistry()
    {
        Scan(
            scan =>
            {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                scan.With(new ControllerConvention());
            });

        For<IUnitOfWork>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use(() => new ApplicationDbContext());
    }
```

But structure map doesn't work and gives me this exception:

> An exception of type 'StructureMap.StructureMapConfigurationException'
>   occurred in StructureMap.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'MEF.ServiceLayer.IProductService'

So my question is this, How can structure map scan another class library other then main project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to add the assembly that contains the IProductService.  For example

```
Scan(
   scan =>
      {
         scan.TheCallingAssembly();
         scan.WithDefaultConventions();
         // Add the assembly that contains a certain type
         scan.AssemblyContainingType<IProductService>();
         scan.With(new ControllerConvention());
      }
    );
```

If the above doesnt work, it would be the lack of a default constructor in the `ProductServce`.  Try adding the following:

```
public class ProductService : IProductService
{
   readonly IDbSet<Product> _products;
   [DefaultConstructor]
   public AccountController()
   {

   }

   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it work now. But instead of adding `AssemblyContainingType`, I just added `Assembly`, since i might delete `IProductService` in future.

Answer (score 0):

If you have referenced the project that contains `IProductService`, You can use Assembly method and pass project name:

```
Scan(scan =>
     {
                // YourProject.Service: The project that contains IProductService
                scan.Assembly("YourProject.Service");
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
     });
```